# xcode 6 Run my app on my IOS device without a developer account?

Tags: ios, xcode6, device

I ***tried everything*** and watched a lot of videos but I have not been finding a solution.
I hope you can answer quickly.

Comment: It is not possible. You have to be either team member of some developer account or you have to have your own account. Otherwise, it is not possible. One way would be to have other people's developer identity and p12 key exported and added to your machine, but that might not be possible, since you have to access keychain to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like insane-36 said, it's impossible to put your app onto your iOS device without an Apple Developer Account. You can go here to find out more: developer.apple.com. I believe to get an account costs $99/year.

There might be another way however, as some apps might be able to be downloaded considering that you have an Apple certificate. I know that some apps such as GBA4IOS (A game boy emulator) have taken this approach in distributing their application. You can look at this [link](http://rileytestut.com/blog/2014/10/08/gba4ios-is-dead-long-live-gba4ios/) to find out more about how they did (and then broke the rules for exceeding the 100 device limit).

Anyways, good luck!

Comment: Unfortunately, the method GBA4IOS uses is outdated, and has been shutdown through correspondence with Apple.